# clone() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, clone

Follow [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

> .clone( [withDataAndEvents] [, deepWithDataAndEvents] )
>
> > **deepWithDataAndEvents** A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data for all children of the cloned element should be copied. By default its value matches the first argument's value (**which defaults to false**).

Here's my code:

HTML :

```
<div id="d1">Click this paragraph to increase text size.<p id="p1">This is another</p></div>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Javascript :

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var para = $("#d1:first").clone(true);
    $("body").append(para);
});
$("#d1").click(function(){
   $(this).animate({fontSize:"+=1px"});
});
$("#p1").click(function(){
   $(this).css({color:"green"});
});
```

When I click button, #p1 changes to be green . Follow api I use **clone(true)**, deepWithDataAndEvents must be false and #p1 can't be affected . I use jQuery v1.8.2

Comment: So you want nothing to happen, when you click on cloned p1 or cloned d1 if I understand correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you misunderstood the part of the documentation that says:

> **deepWithDataAndEvents** A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data for all children of the cloned element should be copied. **By
>   default its value matches the first argument's value** (which defaults
>   to false).

Since you provided `true` in the first argument and you did not specify `deepWithDataAndEvents`, *it will default to `true`, not `false`*. To obtain the behavior you're looking for, you should actually write:

```
var para = $("#d1:first").clone(true, false);
```